# Kendo Grid - Lazy Load On Popup Edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC Grid (Razor) in Ajax mode with a popup editor.

As an example say: Customers have orders

User of the application go to a grid that displays all customers. User is allowed to add/edit/delete customers (and their orders). But when the user clicks on edit and the popup editor comes up that is when I want to load orders. I do not want to load orders eagerly since a customer may have many orders and the user may never edit any customer at all.

Seems like this should be a simple thing to do. I have looked through all forums/questions. I have not been able to find such an example. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a bunch!

j

Answer (score 0):

Are the orders already loaded when the initial grid is loaded (are they in the model)?

If not, one way to do this is define a grid in your popup editor and set .Autobind(false) and set its Read action to a Controller/action.

When editing a record, you can fire a .refresh() on the datasource of the Orders grid.

I would need some more info on the structure of the template and the grid.

Comment: Orders are not already loaded. The main customer grid contains customers name and address. On the Edit popup I have to show customers name, allow for edit on customer address, multiple email addresses of customer in a multi-select. I have to also display customers orders in a grid and allow the user to associate an order with several email addresses for notification purposes.

Comment: Orders are not already loaded. The main customer grid contains customers name and address. On the Edit popup I have to show customers name and allow for edit on customer address. The edit popup also shows multiple email addresses of customer in a multi-select. I have to also display customers orders in a grid and allow the user to associate an order with several email addresses for notification purposes.